# Vue 3 <script setup> issues

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

[image: err]

When I try change my scripts on script setup method - I getting error like on screen. On the other hand, with export default and without `<script setup>` , this error has gone. In Vue docs I can't find this decision
Code:

```
<template>
  <button class="nav-link" @click.prevent="logOut">LogOut</button>
  <RouterView />
  <DarkMode />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import DarkMode from './components/DarkMode.vue'
  const logOut = () => {
    this.$store.dispatch('auth/logout')
    this.$router.push('/login')
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss"></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `this` keyword in `<script setup>`. Instead, it uses hooks for lifecycle methods, reactivity, router and stores among other things.

```js
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { useMyStore } from '../stores/myStore';

const route = useRoute();
const myStore = useMyStore();

const input = ref('');

onMounted(() => {
    console.log('onMounted');
})
```

---

Resources:

- https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html

Comment: The question is not about hooks. Lifecycle hooks aren't methods, they are functions. Vue 3 Composition API architecture is more Closure one, not an object-oriented.

Answer (score -1):

There is no [`this` in `<script setup>` or in `setup()`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#basic-usage).

> `setup()` itself does not have access to the component instance - this will have a value of `undefined` inside `setup()`(and `<script setup>`). You can access Composition-API-exposed values from Options API, but not the other way around.

Please refer [here on how to use Vue Router with Composition API](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#accessing-the-router-and-current-route-inside-setup)

And [here for Vuex & Composition API](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html)

Comment: Please write some minimal code with example, not just paste links to documentation.